# Changing xml layouts using setContentView() by passing a "string" into its parameter?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

something like..

```
String string1 = "R.layout.main";
setContentView(string1);
```

How do i go about doing that? Or is their a similar way of doing it? Or am i doing it the wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that the getResources().getIdentifier() method mentioned in all of the answers below 'may' not work if you obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int id= getResources().getIdentifier("main", "layout", "yourpackagename"),

setContentView(id);
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

You should use the method

```
setContentView(getResources().getIdentifier("main","layout","applicationpackage"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("main", "layout", "package");
setContentView(id)  // Whatever you may give to view..
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get string to id (int) value

```
String string1 = "main";
setContentView(getResources().getIdentifier("layout/" + string1, null, getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

getString(this.getResources().getIdentifier("stringYouWantToConvertInInteger","string",getPackageName()))